# TSQL Geometry:Get records which either havea given point(lat,long)(Point is in the shape) or is near the shape

Tags: t-sql, geometry, latitude-longitude

I have zillow neighborhood data and is successfully imported to DB(thanx to http://shapefilesource.codeplex.com). Now i want to write an SP which will take lat,long and will return all record in which given point lies or is near to them. How can I achieve this in TSQL or do I need to use CLR.

Comment: How do you define "near" the shape?

Comment: I will provide a radius let say 1 km.Any shape which will fall with in one km

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should be able using the function [STBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933965.aspx) and [STIntersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933962.aspx). Maybe these pages may help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2008/10/24/sql-2008-spatial-samples-part-n-1-of-n-stbuffer.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx